# Unsupported expression error: m => m when running tests in visual studio

Tags: c#, moq

I'm learning ASP.NET and I came across the following error. I'm learning to work with aspnet and I'm learning the testing part.

Below is the error that is giving and my source code.

> System.NotSupportedException : Unsupported expression: m =>
> m.Categorias Non-overridable members (here: Context.get_Categorias)
> may not be used in setup / verification expressions.

```
using CursoMVC.Models;
using CursosApi.Controllers;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Moq;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xunit;

namespace TesteCurso
{
    public class CategoriasControllerTest
    {
        private readonly Mock<DbSet<Categoria>> _mockSet;
        private readonly Mock<Context> _mockContext;
        private readonly Categoria _categoria;
        
        public CategoriasControllerTest()
        {
            _mockSet     = new Mock<DbSet<Categoria>>();
            _mockContext = new Mock<Context>();
            _categoria   = new Categoria {Id=1, Descricao = "Teste Categoria"};

           _mockContext.Setup(m => m.Categorias).Returns(_mockSet.Object);

           _mockContext.Setup(m => m.Categorias.FindAsync(1)).ReturnsAsync(_categoria);

//_mockContext.Setup(m => m.SetModified(_categoria));
//
           // _mockContext.Setup(m => m.SaveChangesAsync(It.IsAny<CancellationToken>())).ReturnsAsync(1);
        }

        [Fact]
        public async Task Get_Categoria()
        {
            var service = new CategoriasController(_mockContext.Object);

            await service.GetCategoria(1);

            _mockSet.Verify(m => m.FindAsync(1),Times.Once);

            

        }
    }
}
```

can you help me?

Comment: I changed the tags from ASP.NET and EF Core to Moq, because this is an exception by Moq a mocking framework.

Comment: The error message tells you that the `Categorias` property must be overridable, i.e. `virtual`. The reason is that a mock is class used for testing that replaces an actual class with another implementation to provide testable data. Usually you would mock against an interface, but here you mock a class DbSet<>. The mocking framework therefore needs to create a mock class deriving from DbSet and override the mocked properties and methods with its own implementation providing the test data. This of course requires the mocked properties and methods to be virtual.

Comment: @OP Which version of Entity Framework are you using?